# Writing to text file gives me errors

Tags: c#, file-io, compiler-errors

The code below gives me three compiler errors. They are as follows:

1. The type or namespace name 'TextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
3. The name 'filename' does not exist in the current context

Can anyone provide some clarification as to why these errors are occurring, and how I can fix them?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filename.txt)) {
      writer.WriteLine("First name: {0}", textBox1.Text);
      writer.WriteLine("Last name: {0}", textBox2.Text);
      writer.WriteLine("Phone number: {0}", maskedTextBox1.Text);
      writer.WriteLine("Date of birth: {0}", textBox4.Text);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Error 1 and Error 2, make sure you are `using System.IO;`

For Error 3, if the name of the file to be read is "filename.text", make sure you place the quotes like so:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("filename.txt"))
```

because otherwise it is trying to find a variable `filename` and property `txt` rather than the string "filename.txt".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing a using directive for the `System.IO` namespace, which is where both the `TextWriter` and `File` classes are located. Add the following line at the top of your file, this should resolve your first two errors:

```
using System.IO;
```

Secondly, the `File.CreateText()` method takes a string as a parameter. In your code, "`filename.txt`" is not a string. Use this line instead:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("filename.txt") {
```

Comment: Please fix "missing a reference".  A reference is for an assembly, he's only missing a *using directive*.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.CreateText(filename.txt)
```

You need to put the filename in quotes if it's a filename, or use a proper variable name otherwise.

e.g.

```
File.CreateText("filename.txt");
```

or

```
File.CreateText(path);
```

And as donut said, add `using System.IO` to top of file.

Comment: Huh?  He is missing a namespace reference.

Comment: @Ed Swangren - See 3rd error: "The name 'filename' does not exist in the current context"  He needs quotes around it. Maybe you aren't familiar with this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

Comment: No kidding.  "namespace reference" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Beemer - you've got enough rep to fix that.  Why didn't you?